# how to remove elements based on criteria from 3D array in python

Tags: python, arrays

For a 3D array like this:

```
import numpy as np  
m = np.random.rand(5,4,3)
```

What's an efficient way to remove all the elements meeting such conditions ?

> m[:,:,0] > 0.5 & m[:,:,1] > 0.5 & m[:,:,2] < 0.5

Comment: What do you refer to when you say 1st, 2nd and 3rd dimension? The first 3x2 block? or the first row in every 3x2 block?

Comment: This is a 3D array and each 'element' is just a value which is positioned on 3-way coordination. However, each element is connected to all 3 dimensions. You might be confused with thinking that every 'element' is a triplet. Please clarify, maybe with an example.

Comment: @RonU I was indeed. Now revised it and hopefully the question works.

Comment: @santoku you have a typo you should `m = np.random.rand(5,4,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still undefined but I'll answer to what I think you meant to ask. The problem with your question is that if we remove some of the elements you won't get a proper tensor (multidimensional np array) since it will have 'holes' in it. So instead of removing I'll write a way to set those values to np.nan (you can set them to whatever you'll see fit, such as -1 or None, etc...). To make it more clear, **Any element from m cannot meet those three conditions at once**, since they're each corresponding to different elements. Answering to your question directly will just give you the same array.

Also, it is worth mentioning that although efficiency will not cut-edge in this case, as you're going to check a condition for every value anyway, but I'll write a common numpy'ish way of doing so:

```
m[np.where(m[:,:,:2] > 0.5)] = np.nan
m[np.where(m[:,:,2] < 0.5)] = np.nan
```

What we did here is setting all values that met with a part of your condition to np.nan. This, is by creating a boolean np.array of elements that meet with a condition (the `m[:,:,:2] > 0.5` part) and then with `np.where` check what coordination are the values which set to true. Then, with slicing to those coordination only from m, we gave them a new value with broadcasting.